# Query an existing Sqlite3 database using Knex within React

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, knex.js

**TL;DR: I can't read my sqlite database using Knex in React.**

Using create-react-app I create a new single page application:

`npx create-react-app knex-react && cd knex-react`

I install knex, sqlite3 (and also mssql, unsure why but I get an error otherwise):

`npm install knex sqlite3 mssql`

I change directory to public and create a new database:

```sh
cd public
sqlite3 test.db
```

I create a file called insert.sql with the following text inside it:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;

CREATE TABLE people (
    forename text NOT NULL,  
    surname text NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (forename, surname)
);

INSERT INTO people (forename, surname)
VALUES ('Bob', 'White'),
('Brad', 'Brown'),
('Jill', 'Green');
```

at the sqlite prompt I insert this file and test correct:

```
sqlite> .read insert.sql
sqlite> SHOW * FROM people;
```

This produces, as it should:

```
Bob|White
Brad|Brown
Jill|Green
```

I edit src/App.js to read the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
        filename: './test.db'
  },
});

console.log(knex.select().table('people'));

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>Just a paragraph</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I run `npm start` and opening the console log the relevant line reads:

> Builder {client: Client_SQLite3, and: Builder, _single: {…}, _statements: Array(0), _method: "select", …}

This is not what I am expecting, the [documentation](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-select) tells me I should get "an array of objects selected from the database" so Bob, Brad and Jill.  I'm getting nothing.

What am I doing wrong?  Apologies for the long preamble but I wanted to provide a complete minimal example.

I'm using Node: v12.6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

NB - My first assumption was I've placed test.db in the wrong directory.  I've literally tried placing it everywhere with no luck...

Comment: You need to either access the results via .then() or await, you haven’t actually executed the query without that. Also you won’t be able to use knex in the browser, it’s working in development because node is available, in the browser node won’t be available.   https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2270

Comment: Apologies, are you saying my code is wrong, or it simply won't work?  Or both?  If my code is wrong, could you give an example of how I would correct it?

Comment: `knex.select().table('people').then(people => console.log(people))`. That being said, you will NOT be able to use Knex in a create-react-app react application. It will not work in the browser when built for production.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Understand that it won't work in production (tho didn't before, so thanks).  However this has been bugging me for such a long time, I'd be happy to get it working just in development!  The code you suggested gets me closer... but I now get an error:

`index.js:65 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.driver.Database is not a constructor
    at index.js:65
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client_SQLite3.acquireRawConnection (index.js:64)
    at create (client.js:289)`

Comment: That error sounds like exactly like the type of errors you would get running it in the browser. Try instead at minimum creating a simple server application, such as express and put your knex logic there, exposing endpoints that you can request via HTTP from the react application. You will not be able to do this in create-react-app.